# How to unit test automated function calls

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I have a counter at where I can register my component. The register method takes an element and the time (amount of ticks) when to callback.

It's something like:

Service.ts:

```
registerElement(element: any, ticksToCallback: number): void {
  this.sortIntoTree(this.rootTreeElement, ticksToCallback, element);
}
```

After the element is due, it is taken out of a binary tree and the element's callback function is called.

Service.ts:

```
 if (element.associatedObject.timeOutCallback() === 'function') {
   element.associatedObject.timeOutCallback();
   }
```

Registering is simply:

Component.ts:

```
this.service.registerElement(this, givenAmountOfTicks);
```

so I'm providing the element and after a given amount of ticks, the element's own callback function is called.

Is there a way to implement a timeOutCallback() function in a testbed and have it trace the calls? Is 'this' referring to something different inside a testbed?

I know async tasks have to be implemented in a beforeEach(), so I'm running:

Service.spec.ts

```
describe('Service', () => {
  beforeEach( () =>  {
    function foo() {
      Service.prototype.registerElement(this, 5); // more calls here
      let returncount = 0;
      function timeOutCallback(): void {
         console.log("in timeout Callback");
         returncount ++;
      }
    }
    setTimeout(foo, 5005);
 });

 it('should instantiate a view callbacks and call the method', (done) => {
  expect(this.returncount).toBe(1); // scale number for more calls
  done();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate architecture based on code and description you provided:

```
// Your service
@Injectable()
class SomeService {
  rootTreeElement;

  registerElement(element: any, ticksToCallback: number): void {
    this.sortIntoTree(this.rootTreeElement, ticksToCallback, element);
  }

  private sortIntoTree(rootTreeElement, ticksToCallback, element) {
    for (let i = 0; i < ticksToCallback; i++) {
      if (element.associatedObject.timeOutCallback) { // You can check like this if callback is provided
        element.associatedObject.timeOutCallback();
      }
    }
  }
}

// Tests
describe('SomeService', () => {
  let service: SomeService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [SomeService]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(SomeService);
  });

  it('should call callback 5 times', () => {
    const mockElement = {associatedObject: {timeOutCallback: createSpy()}};

    service.registerElement(mockElement, 5);

    expect(mockElement.associatedObject.timeOutCallback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(5);
  });
});
```

What we're doing here is create mock `element` (which is component as you mentioned) and pass it to `registerElement` method of your service. Note that we only provide `timeOutCallback` method since we only test that but you can spy on other methods or provide some fake values for properties if you use them.